# Gremlin Query for Flights Between Origin and Destination without Transferring On AWS Neptune

Tags: graph, graph-theory, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm attempting to set up a graph data that is representative of airline routes in order to determine routes between an origin and destination between a certain time period.

My vertices are the airports, here is some of the CSV I loaded into Neptune:

```
~id,code:String
PPG,PPG
CMH,CMH
LGB,LGB
HRL,HRL
TUS,TUS
MEM,MEM
YWG,YWG
ICN,ICN
ATL,ATL
MIA,MIA
IND,IND
TPA,TPA
DEN,DEN
FLL,FLL
DAL,DAL
MDW,MDW
PHX,PHX
HOU,HOU
MCO,MCO
SJU,SJU
```

And here are some of my edges or the flights between airports and their properties:

```
~id,origin:String,destination:String,start_datetime:Date,end_datetime:Date,equipment_type:String,tail_number:String,flight_number:String,~from,~to,~label
1912MIA20230612,MIA,ATL,2023-06-12T09:10:00Z,2023-06-12T11:00:00Z,AB1,111111,1912,MIA,ATL,FLIGHT
0468IND20230612,IND,PHX,2023-06-12T09:20:00Z,2023-06-12T13:00:00Z,AB2,222222,468,IND,PHX,FLIGHT
2826TPA20230612,TPA,DEN,2023-06-12T09:20:00Z,2023-06-12T16:42:00Z,AB3,333333,2826,TPA,DEN,FLIGHT
3629FLL20230612,FLL,ATL,2023-06-12T09:35:00Z,2023-06-12T11:25:00Z,AB4,444444,3629,FLL,ATL,FLIGHT
2970FLL20230612,FLL,DAL,2023-06-12T09:45:00Z,2023-06-12T16:55:00Z,AB1,555555,2970,FLL,DAL,FLIGHT
1855MDW20230612,MDW,PHX,2023-06-12T10:00:00Z,2023-06-12T15:27:00Z,AB1,666666,1855,MDW,PHX,FLIGHT
2910HOU20230612,HOU,ATL,2023-06-12T10:00:00Z,2023-06-12T12:00:00Z,AB5,777777,2910,HOU,ATL,FLIGHT
0169ATL20230612,ATL,DEN,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:30:00Z,AB3,888888,169,ATL,DEN,FLIGHT
1736MCO20230612,MCO,SJU,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999999,1736,MCO,SJU,FLIGHT
```

I've been able to get a query working that gets direct flights from point A to point B between two times using the following Gremlin query. (Sorry for the poor formatting, i've only been sending directly through postman to my Neptune instance so I don't understand the best practice towards formatting Gremlin queries)

```
g.V().
  has('code', 'MDW').as('a').
  outE('FLIGHT').as('e').
  filter(
    select('e').
    values('start_datetime').
    is(gte(datetime('2023-06-12T10:00:00Z')))).
  inV().
  has('code', 'ATL').
  filter(
    select('e').
    values('end_datetime').
    is(lte(datetime('2023-07-19T00:00:00Z')))).
  select('a', 'e').by(valueMap('code')).by(valueMap())
```

This will print out all of the direct flights from MDW to ATL between those two dates.

I need to further expand this query to first include non-transfer segments. A non transfer segment would be a journey that could get to point A to point B without changing planes.

How you determine that is by the plane's tail number, if the tail number stays the same from point A to point X to point B then it would be considered a non-transfer segment (Let's cap this at 4 stops though, so at most point B (our destination) would be the 4th stop). Eventually I will probably have to expand this to flights also include non-transfers but I can worry about that a bit later.

I'm still in the infancy of creating this graph database and it's been awesome setting this up to hopefully do something cool in the future, but I've gotten stuck in the mud on the querying aspect of it. If you also have any improvements that I could potentially make to the actual vertices / edges that would be awesome as well.

I potentially thought about maybe making the vertices an airport + a date, so PPG20230611, to potentially improve performance, but I haven't gotten to a point where I can even begin to think about improving performance since I don't even have a working query for MVP.

Comment: gremlint.com provides good interface to format gremlin queries.

Answer (score 0):

I added a couple of rows to your input load files to get some more data to add some routes from MDW to ATL with multiple hop lengths. The data added also has same tail_numbers and 2 tail_numbers in the path.

The data I added is:

```
PPG,PPG
CMH,CMH
LGB,LGB
HRL,HRL
TUS,TUS
MEM,MEM
YWG,YWG
ICN,ICN
ATL,ATL
MIA,MIA
IND,IND
TPA,TPA
DEN,DEN
FLL,FLL
DAL,DAL
MDW,MDW
PHX,PHX
HOU,HOU
MCO,MCO
SJU,SJU
```

Edges:

```
~id,origin:String,destination:String,start_datetime:Date,end_datetime:Date,equipment_type:String,tail_number:String,flight_number:String,~from,~to,~label
1912MIA20230612,MIA,ATL,2023-06-12T09:10:00Z,2023-06-12T11:00:00Z,AB1,111111,1912,MIA,ATL,FLIGHT
0468IND20230612,IND,PHX,2023-06-12T09:20:00Z,2023-06-12T13:00:00Z,AB2,222222,468,IND,PHX,FLIGHT
2826TPA20230612,TPA,DEN,2023-06-12T09:20:00Z,2023-06-12T16:42:00Z,AB3,333333,2826,TPA,DEN,FLIGHT
3629FLL20230612,FLL,ATL,2023-06-12T09:35:00Z,2023-06-12T11:25:00Z,AB4,444444,3629,FLL,ATL,FLIGHT
2970FLL20230612,FLL,DAL,2023-06-12T09:45:00Z,2023-06-12T16:55:00Z,AB1,555555,2970,FLL,DAL,FLIGHT
1855MDW20230612,MDW,PHX,2023-06-12T10:00:00Z,2023-06-12T15:27:00Z,AB1,666666,1855,MDW,PHX,FLIGHT
2910HOU20230612,HOU,ATL,2023-06-12T10:00:00Z,2023-06-12T12:00:00Z,AB5,777777,2910,HOU,ATL,FLIGHT
0169ATL20230612,ATL,DEN,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:30:00Z,AB3,888888,169,ATL,DEN,FLIGHT
1736MCO20230612,MCO,SJU,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999999,1736,MCO,SJU,FLIGHT

1_FLIGHT,MDW,PHX,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999999,1736,MDW,PHX,FLIGHT
2_FLIGHT,PHX,ATL,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999999,1736,PHX,ATL,FLIGHT
3_FLIGHT,MDW,IND,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999999,1736,MDW,IND,FLIGHT
4_FLIGHT,IND,PHX,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999999,1736,IND,PHX,FLIGHT
5_FLIGHT,MDW,TPA,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999999,1736,MDW,TPA,FLIGHT
6_FLIGHT,TPA,IND,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999999,1736,TPA,IND,FLIGHT
8_FLIGHT,MDW,FLL,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999999,1736,MDW,FLL,FLIGHT
9_FLIGHT,FLL,ATL,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999998,1736,FLL,ATL,FLIGHT
7_FLIGHT,MDW,ATL,2023-06-12T10:05:00Z,2023-06-12T16:52:00Z,AB1,999999,1736,MDW,ATL,FLIGHT
```

Now I run the query

```
g.V().
  has('code', 'MDW').as('a').
  repeat(
    outE('FLIGHT').
    has('start_datetime', gte(datetime('2023-06-12T10:00:00Z'))).as('a').
    inV()).
    until(loops().is(4).or().has('code', 'ATL')). // loops count can be changed to the number of max hops needed.
  has('code', 'ATL').
  path().
    by('code').
    by(
      valueMap('tail_number').with(WithOptions.tokens, WithOptions.ids)).
    as('b').
  select(all, 'a').
  where(unfold().values('tail_number').dedup().count().is(1)). // The number of planes to change
  select('b')

RESULT: 
1   path[MDW, {<T.id: 1>: '7_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, ATL]
2   path[MDW, {<T.id: 1>: '1_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, PHX, {<T.id: 1>: '2_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, ATL]
3   path[MDW, {<T.id: 1>: '3_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, IND, {<T.id: 1>: '4_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, PHX, {<T.id: 1>: '2_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, ATL]
4   path[MDW, {<T.id: 1>: '5_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, TPA, {<T.id: 1>: '6_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, IND, {<T.id: 1>: '4_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, PHX, {<T.id: 1>: '2_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, ATL]
```

if I change the total number of tail_numbers to 2, I get the result as:

```
1   path[MDW, {<T.id: 1>: '8_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, FLL, {<T.id: 1>: '9_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999998'}, ATL]
2   path[MDW, {<T.id: 1>: '1855MDW20230612', 'tail_number': '666666'}, PHX, {<T.id: 1>: '2_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, ATL]
```

You can change the condition there from `is(1)` to `is(lte(2))` to get all the paths which uses 2 or less planes. This should give you an idea to play around with usecase you want to solve.

This is using repeat step with labelling so it will not run optimized in Neptune when you have lots of data to be traversed.

You could also write queries with manual hops like:

```
g.V().
  has('code', 'MDW').as('a').
  outE('FLIGHT').
  has('start_datetime', gte(datetime('2023-06-12T10:00:00Z'))).as('f1').
  inV().as('d1').
  outE('FLIGHT').
  has('start_datetime', gte(datetime('2023-06-12T10:00:00Z'))).as('f2').
  where(eq('f1')).by('tail_number').
  inV().
  outE('FLIGHT').
  has('start_datetime', gte(datetime('2023-06-12T10:00:00Z'))).as('f3').
  where(eq('f1')).by('tail_number').
  where(eq('f2')).by('tail_number').
  inV().
  path().
    by('code').
    by(
      valueMap('tail_number').with(WithOptions.tokens, WithOptions.ids))

RESULT: 
path[MDW, {<T.id: 1>: '3_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, IND, {<T.id: 1>: '4_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, PHX, {<T.id: 1>: '2_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, ATL]
2   path[MDW, {<T.id: 1>: '5_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, TPA, {<T.id: 1>: '6_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, IND, {<T.id: 1>: '4_FLIGHT', 'tail_number': '999999'}, PHX]
```

But these sort of query patterns would give you only those paths which are of exact 3 hops. Unfortunately this query is also not converted fully to native steps. So can undergo slowness with huge amount of data.